# iPhone iOS10 orientation media query failing in Mail App

Tags: css, email, media-queries, ios10, screen-orientation

I am trying to target an iPhone 7 in landscape or portrait mode within an email which only needs to be viewable in iOS 10's Mail App.

When I test the below code either in Chrome's dev tool, iOS simulator or my iPhone 7's Safari browser everything works fine. The color changes from green <=> blue when I change orientation. Unfortunately, when I send this html file as an email my mail app does not seem to recognize **portrait** mode.

If I comment out the **landscape** section and only **portrait** remains, none of the css gets attached; alternatively, if I *only* have **landscape** the styling remains regardless of my screen's orientation.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  .
  .
  .
  .
  @media screen 
      and (min-width: 375px) 
      and (max-width: 667px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
      and (orientation: landscape) { 
       .handheld .test {
         background-color: green;
         }
       }

  @media screen 
    and (min-width: 375px) 
    and (max-width: 667px) 
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
    and (orientation: portrait) { 
       .handheld .test {
         background-color: blue;
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue for sometime as well. With emails i have noticed the email simply moves with the screen on screen rotation. Android on the other hand loads the the email again when the device orientation changes.

I found an article at [Email on Acid Blog](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_media_queries_and_device_orientation) which answers your question i guess. iOS email client when rotated doesn't respond to other media queries (unless maybe when the email is opened in that device orientation).